# How to make a hat vector character in xmgrace

Tags: character, symbols, xmgrace

How can I make a hat vector character in XMGRACE? I've been trying all combinations for two hours now.

Comment: Hello! Please edit your question and remove the duplicate words. Perhaps you can show some code of what you've tried so far.

Comment: Maybe you'll find advice how to ask effectively here: [mcve]

Comment: Hello! Please edit your question and remove the duplicate words. Perhaps you can show some code of what you've tried so far. (sees double).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be honest, doing something like that is annoyingly difficult in xmgrace. In this case, the most easy route would be to use a superscript and shift it to the left with the `\h` command:

```
v\S\h{-0.6}^
```

which results in something like this:

[image: a hat-capped v]

It is not particularly pretty, but it does the job (I guess).

The full list of available commands can be found [here](http://plasma-gate.weizmann.ac.il/Grace/doc/UsersGuide.html#ss7.1).

Comment: @Mona Happy to help! If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted by clicking the green check mark. This helps to more easily find questions that still don't have answers.